# jQuery/php determine which button triggered a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to send to php the result of an ajax form, however which button was pressed (submit or cancel) is important to the php code, but is lost during the ajax. I am trying to uncover which button was pressed to submit the form, but my code is not working.

Can someone point out what is going wrong here?

```
$('.form').live('submit', function(event) {

    var messageTo = $(this).next();
    var button = event.target;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    data = data + "&" + button.name + "=" + button.value;

    $.post(
        'a.php',
        data,
        function(data){
                messageTo.html(data.message);               
        }, "json"
    );

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? live() is not a good option.

Comment: To follow up on @Chibuzo's comment above, if you're using a modern version of jQuery you should really switch the .live() to a .on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: do you have WebInspector/Firebug turned on? what's in your Network tab after you press submit button?

Answer (score 0):

This line should give you the element that triggered the event

```
var button = event.target.nodeName;
```